# Want to get list of 0kb files in local PC from FTP folder?

Tags: windows, cmd, ftp, size, echo

FTP image

I want to get the list of 0kb files in to my local computer.?

Please find the attached screenshot

Comment: Please find the attached screenshot
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1CvAl.png

Comment: The screenshot shows folders. How does that relate to your question? Do you want to recursively scan remote directory tree and list all empty files in any remote subfolder?